# Combine an animation with multiple motion capture (bvh) file

Tags: animation, motion-capture

I have a model made with makehuman 1.1.1 and two motion capture bvh files (walk and run).

I want the run animation to start at the end of the walk.

I cannot figure out how to start the run animation at the last coordinates (x,y,z) of the walk animation.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: The best if you remove the rootmotion and move the whole armature object.

Comment: Indeed that works but i would like to preserve the motion capture and just add an offset to the initial location of the second action.